# Difference between "There is one" vs "there is at least one"

Tags: quantifiers, predicate-logic

Is there a difference between the two?

I want to say there isn't, but discrete math sometimes doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Just wanted to verify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

In some situations the formulation "There is at least one" is preferred, to make sure that "There is one" is not confused with "There is exactly one".